# URL changed unexpectedly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, cakephp

I have a little problem with url in action of a form post. My form looks like this

```
<form action="../method" type="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and my method looks like

```
function method()
{
   $bool=dosomething();
   if($bool)
   {
      $this->redirect('mainpage');
   }
   else
   {
      $this->redirect('currentpage');
   }
}
```

I would like my button press event to direct me to the current page if teh $bool value is evaluated to false. But the first time I access to the current page, the url is e.g `http://localhost/dir/controllers/method` as I hover my mouse over the submit button
But when the above $bool becomes false (second time reloaded), the above button's executed url becomes `http://localhost/dir/method`.

What should I fix now ?

Comment: why are you posting the form to `../` try `echo site_url('controller/method')` in action

Comment: why not just using the form helper which prevents you from your many mistakes you made here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a form to redirect.

You can activate the url_helper in autoload like this :

> autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Replace your form by this :

> echo anchor('controllers/method', 'My text', 'title="myTitle"');

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just like Broncha said: the action attribute in your form tag is wrong.
"../" means parent directory, so he "goes one level up".

Just use Cakes Form Helper for creating Forms:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Or the url() - method of Cakes HtmlHelper:
[http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aurl)